# Use Nchan to post to logged in users only

Tags: laravel, nginx, nchan

I am setting up an application with realtime events using nchan (https://github.com/slact/nchan). The application itself is built on the Laravel framework. However, for now everyone that subscripes to specific sub-channel will get new events as soon infomation is pushed to the corresponing pub-channel.
I want to limit that so only logged in users should be able to subscribe to events. Hence, if I am not logged in, it should not be possible to create a websocket and listen for events from for example http://www.example.com/chat/pubchat?id=some_id.

Is there any way to make this possible?
As far as I know, I cannot use Nginx/Nchan to make database queries to get only logged on users that way. And Laravel itself cannot limit subscribers since that is handled by Nginx/Nchan (but on the other side, can make database queries).

Thanks for any tips!

EDIT: Seems that I might can use the Drizzle module (https://github.com/openresty/drizzle-nginx-module) and use the session ID as identifier. So if that ID is not present in the session table the connection will be blocked.